# What download documentation does for Maven dependency in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ.

I know that by default Maven downloads only a Jar file. So, when I want to see the source code, it shows the decompiled java code.

When I say download sources on the Maven tab on the right, it downloads the real source code with comments written.

This is what download sources does, but `download sources` and `download documentation` are separated. What download documentation does? Aren't those comments a documentation? What documentation it downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It downloads the `javadoc` jar for the dependency. It contains documentation in HTML format that is pre-built from the sources using the `javadoc` tool.

Maven dependencies usually come in 3 files:

- attach-source-javadoc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- attach-source-javadoc-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
- attach-source-javadoc-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar

This action downloads the latter (if available).

In IntelliJ IDEA javadoc can be used to display **External documentation** in the browser (Shift+F1). **Quick documentation** (Ctrl+Q) will also work from just the sources and doesn't require javadoc.